# django custom command based on python script

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a custom command for django that can be run with `python manage.py cert_transparency` and i'm almost there but i'm having a little trouble. The purpose of this one is to create a 24/7 running command in the background which I just run in a docker container.

I'm receiving this error message

```
certificate_update: 0cert [00:00, ?cert/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/src/scraper/management/commands/cert_transparency.py", line 184, in handle
    certstream.listen_for_events(callback, url=certstream_url)
NameError: name 'callback' is not defined
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is just import this [script](https://github.com/x0rz/phishing_catcher/blob/master/catch_phishing.py) as a custom management command in django.

[image: Directory Structure]

cert_transparency.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import re
import math

import certstream
import tqdm
import yaml
import time
import os
from Levenshtein import distance
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from tld import get_tld
from .confusables import unconfuse


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Scrapes calidogs websocket for cert renewals and rates them.'
    
    def score_domain(self, domain):
        """Score `domain`.

    The highest score, the most probable `domain` is a phishing site.

    Args:
        domain (str): the domain to check.

    Returns:
        int: the score of `domain`.
        """
        score = 0
        for t in suspicious['tlds']:
            if domain.endswith(t):
                score += 20

    # Remove initial '*.' for wildcard certificates bug
        if domain.startswith('*.'):
            domain = domain[2:]

    # Removing TLD to catch inner TLD in subdomain (ie. paypal.com.domain.com)
        try:
            res = get_tld(domain, as_object=True, fail_silently=True, fix_protocol=True)
            domain = '.'.join([res.subdomain, res.domain])
        except Exception:
            pass

    # Higer entropy is kind of suspicious
    #score += int(round(entropy(domain)*10))

    # Remove lookalike characters using list from http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39
        domain = unconfuse(domain)

        words_in_domain = re.split("\W+", domain)

    # ie. detect fake .com (ie. *.com-account-management.info)
        if words_in_domain[0] in ['com', 'net', 'org']:
            score += 10

    # Testing keywords
        for word in suspicious['keywords']:
            if word in domain:
                score += suspicious['keywords'][word]

    # Testing Levenshtein distance for strong keywords (>= 70 points) (ie. paypol)
        for key in [k for (k,s) in suspicious['keywords'].items() if s >= 70]:
        # Removing too generic keywords (ie. mail.domain.com)
            for word in [w for w in words_in_domain if w not in ['email', 'mail', 'cloud']]:
                if distance(str(word), str(key)) == 1:
                    score += 70

    # Lots of '-' (ie. www.paypal-datacenter.com-acccount-alert.com)
        if 'xn--' not in domain and domain.count('-') >= 4:
            score += domain.count('-') * 3

    # Deeply nested subdomains (ie. www.paypal.com.security.accountupdate.gq)
        if domain.count('.') >= 3:
            score += domain.count('.') * 3

        return score


    def callback(self, message, context):
        """Callback handler for certstream events."""
        if message['message_type'] == "heartbeat":
            return

        if message['message_type'] == "certificate_update":
            all_domains = message['data']['leaf_cert']['all_domains']

            for domain in all_domains:
                pbar.update(1)
                score = score_domain(self, domain.lower())

            # If issued from a free CA = more suspicious
                if "Let's Encrypt" in message['data']['chain'][0]['subject']['aggregated']:
                    score += 10

                if score >= 100:
                    self.stdout.write(tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Suspicious: "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'red', attrs=['underline', 'bold']), score)))
                elif score >= 90:
                    self.stdout.write(tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Suspicious: "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'red', attrs=['underline']), score)))
                elif score >= 80:
                    self.stdout.write(tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Likely    : "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'yellow', attrs=['underline']), score)))
                elif score >= 65:
                    self.stdout.write(tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[+] Potential : "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, attrs=['underline']), score)))

                if score >= 75:
                    with open(log_suspicious, 'a') as f:
                        f.write("{}\n".format(domain))

    def callback(self, message, context):
        """Callback handler for certstream events."""
        if message['message_type'] == "heartbeat":
            return

        if message['message_type'] == "certificate_update":
            all_domains = message['data']['leaf_cert']['all_domains']

            for domain in all_domains:
                pbar.update(1)
                score = score_domain(domain.lower())

            # If issued from a free CA = more suspicious
                if "Let's Encrypt" in message['data']['chain'][0]['subject']['aggregated']:
                    score += 10

                if score >= 100:
                    tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Suspicious: "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'red', attrs=['underline', 'bold']), score))
                elif score >= 90:
                    tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Suspicious: "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'red', attrs=['underline']), score))
                elif score >= 80:
                    tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[!] Likely    : "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, 'yellow', attrs=['underline']), score))
                elif score >= 65:
                    tqdm.tqdm.write(
                    "[+] Potential : "
                    "{} (score={})".format(colored(domain, attrs=['underline']), score))

                if score >= 75:
                    with open(log_suspicious, 'a') as f:
                        f.write("{}\n".format(domain))

                        
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        certstream_url = 'wss://certstream.calidog.io'

        log_suspicious = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/suspicious_domains_'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.log'

        suspicious_yaml = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/suspicious.yaml'

        external_yaml = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/external.yaml'

        pbar = tqdm.tqdm(desc='certificate_update', unit='cert')



        with open(suspicious_yaml, 'r') as f:
            suspicious = yaml.safe_load(f)

        with open(external_yaml, 'r') as f:
            external = yaml.safe_load(f)

        if external['override_suspicious.yaml'] is True:
            suspicious = external
        else:
            if external['keywords'] is not None:
                suspicious['keywords'].update(external['keywords'])

            if external['tlds'] is not None:
                suspicious['tlds'].update(external['tlds'])

        certstream.listen_for_events(callback, url=certstream_url)
```

Comment: It should be `self.callback`, so `certstream.listen_for_events(callback, url=certstream_url)`. You however defined two `callback` methods?

Comment: Ooooops, I've copied the code two times. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll fix it and see if it your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `.callback(…)` method twice, so I think you should remove one of the two. You can pass a reference to the `.callback(…)` method with `self.callback`:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # …
    certstream.listen_for_events(self.callback, url=certstream_url)
```

Comment: I forgot to reply back yesterday. Your solution fixed my issue. Thanks for it!